I do not understand array decay in C..it seems selective
While I pass B[2][3] 2D Array in a function pointer decay is expected.
However that seems to be happening selective only in what I pass as a parameter syntactically.
Here is my code:
#include<stdio.h>

void printArray(int B[][3])
{
     printf("sizeof(B) is : %u\n", sizeof(B)); //When arrays are passed to functions they decay into pointers. 
     printf("sizeof(B[0]) is : %u\n", sizeof(B[0])); //But here I get an array-pointer.Why there is no array to pointer decay here?See results Below.
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int B[2][3] = { {2,3,6},{4,5,8} };
    
    printf("sizeof(B) is : %u\n", sizeof(B));
    printf("sizeof(B[0]) is : %u\n", sizeof(B[0]));

    printArray(B);

    return 0;
}

Here are my results:
sizeof(B) is : 24
sizeof(B[0]) is : 12
sizeof(B) is : 4
sizeof(B[0]) is : 12

C:\Users\Strakizzz\Desktop\C\My Codeschool Projects\Pointers in C?C++\Debug\FunctionsPointersScopeMayhem.exe (process 20660) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .

I was expecting while printing sizeof(B[0]) from my called function to get 4 bytes as well like when i calculated the sizeof(B) in the same function:
void printArray().

.Why do I get these results, what is happening under the hood?

Unrelated: %u is the wrone conversion specifier for a sizeof. It should be %zu

As you know of an array decaying into a pointer to its first element when passed as an argument to a function, please develop the thought about what your expectation of sizeof(B) inside the function should be in more depth.

Nope, i still get the same results.Also i program in vs2022 and the specifier for unsigned int is %u according to msdn.

I was expecting to get 24bytes for sizeof(B) or 4bytes for sizeof(B[0]) as  results  from printArray().If both gave me 4bytes it would be array decay.However sizeof(B[0]) called from printArray gives me 12bytes as a result.The last 2 values which come from printArray are confusing.

sizeof and the address-of operator & accept lvalues, so pointer decay does not occur (since pointer decay happens when lvalues decay to rvalues).

sizeof is not a function. It is an operator, even if you use ()'s with it. Its operand is one of the cases where array-pointer decay does not occur. B in printArray has type point to array of 3 ints. So B[0] has type of array of 3 ints. So 12 is correct.

Raymond i need some time to confirm your answer , I am looking for lvalues and rvalues.

Does this answer your question? C sizeof a passed array

@Sotiris Re: "I was expecting to get 24bytes for sizeof(B)" - Think about it: After the decay into a pointer to the first element, what size does a pointer have?

12 is indeed correct Avi.But I have given parameter int B[][3] in printArray().

Ted I agree, the weird thing is that it happens only in parameter B[][3] while B[0] in the same function gives correct result 12.

@Sotiris Why is that surprising? What type is B[0]? Calculation: It's an int[3]. Given that  sizeof(int) is 4 and you have 3 of them, 12 seems reasonable.

Raymond i think both B and B[0] are lvalues.Both give a memory location since I have a 2d array.

Well then what is B Ted?My array is B[2][3].

? So the parameter B of printArray() is a pointer to an array of 3 ints. That makes B[0] an array of 3 ints, which does not decay back to a pointer when used with sizeof. I don't understand The "But" in your comment. See Array to pointer conversion about 3/4 of the way down And note: "When an array type is used in a function parameter list, it is transformed to the corresponding pointer type . . . the function's actual parameter type is pointer type"

@Sotiris Re: "what is B Ted?" - You declared B as int B[][3] so I'm not really geting the question if you understand the decay. The declaration could just as well be written int(*B)[3], which is the same declaration - hence, dereferencing, like you do in B[0] would give you an int[3].

void printArray(int B[][3]) is notation for void printArray(int (*B)[3]) in C. B in main() is int B[2][3], but the B parameter in printArray is a different variable that happens to have the same name. it is int (*B)[3]. A pointer, not an array. Which is why printArray()'s sizeof B is sizeof a pointer, not an array of any dimensions.

Ok, that makes more sense, a NEW variable is created to pass the array by reference.Correct?

@Sotiris Re: "a NEW variable is created" - No variables are created. Variables are abstractions we use in "high" level languages to make it easy to make programs.

Do you mean : sizeof( int )  ?

So what is happening then?? int (*B)[3] pointer variable has the same address with...?

@James sizeof(int[3])

@Sotiris Since B is a pointer to an int[3], the size you'll get when dereferencing B will be the size of a single element times the number of elements. sizeof(int) * 3

I need time to study it..but my question is not about main() results, only about the results   in printArray(),which are the last 2.

@Sotiris Those results will become clear when you just think about the pointer decay. int[3][4] decays into an int(*][4] etc.

@James Are you addressing anything in particular?

@TedLyngmo sizeof(int[3]) == 12 , he want to get the number =4 .

@James What OP wants from a decayed pointer and what is possible are two very different things. Do you agree? I still don't get what your warning: 'sizeof'... comment was about or who that was the intended reader.

The int (*B)[3] parameter has its own address, not the same as anything else (unless it is optimized to be stored in a processor register). Function parameters are effectively local variables that come into being at the time of the function call in the C language model. I'm not clear what the objection to "a NEW variable is created" is. Sounds fine to me for general understanding though I'll allow there might be a more precise and proper way of expressing it.

@Sotiris You might get this warning message  if you noticed it warning: 'sizeof' on array function parameter 'B' will return size of 'int (*)[3]' [-Wsizeof-array-argument] .

Thank you all for your help my question has been answered.

See also my answers here where I talk about it: How to pass a multidimensional array to a function in C and C++ and Passing an array as an argument to a function in C.

The array "decay", which occurs in many contexts in which an array type is used, replaces the array type with a pointer to the first element of an array.  So an int a[5] decays to an int *.
For a two-dimensional array, i.e. an array of arrays, it works like this:  int B[2][3] decays to an int (*)[3], which is a pointer to an array of three int.  That's because B is an array of two elements, with each element being an array of three int.
In printArray, the compiler automatically adjusts the B parameter to have type int (*B)[3].  B is a pointer, which on your machine has size 4, and B[0] has type int [3], so it has size sizeof(int) * 3 which on your machine is 12.  So printArray prints 4 and 12.
Portability note:  Using %u to print a sizeof value, which has type size_t, is not portable.  Instead, use %zu, which is portable.

So there is no decay happening on B[0], only in function parameter?Thank you for the portability note.

Right, the decay only happens at the top-level.

Thank you Tom that`s exactly what i needed to confirm.

Except when it is the operand of the sizeof, _Alignof, or unary & operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element of T" will be converted, or "decay", to an expression of type "pointer to T" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.
Given the declaration
int B[2][3] = { {2,3,6},{4,5,8} };

in the function call
printArray(B);

the expression B decays from type "2-element array of 3-element array of int" (int [2][3]) to "pointer to 3-element array of int" (int (*)[3]) and what printArray actually receives is a pointer value equivalent to &B[0].
In the context of a function parameter declaration, T a[N] and T a[] are "adjusted" to T *a, so the prototype
void printArray(int B[][3])

is equivalent to
void printArray(int (*B)[3])

As noted above, an array expression won't decay when it's the operand of sizeof, so sizeof B in main will give you the size of the entire array (2 * 3 * sizeof (int)) and sizeof B[0] will give you the size of the first subarray (3 * sizeof (int)).
However, in the printArray function, B is actually a pointer, not an array, so sizeof B gives you the size of the pointer.  However, sizeof B[0] still gives you the size of the first subarray, since the type of the expression B[0] is int [3].

Thank you for taking the time to answer.What answered my question was that decay is only happening when the array passes as a function parameter, that is why B[0] remains int [3] while B[][3] becomes int (*B)[3].
